# Writing a small wrapper for OpenCV

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, wrapper, dllimport

I have a program where I need to do a small amount of image processing. Up to now I used Emgu.CV which worked fine but apparently it isn't optimal concerning performance. Since I only use the AbsDiff, SmoothMedian and Threshold functions from Emgu.CV I decided to write my own wrapper. Actually just for learnings sake.

I tried to add a reference to the OpenCV-dlls, but they couldn't be added.
I read that I have to do it by

```
[DllImport("C:\\opencv\\build\\x86\\vc12\\bin\\highgui.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern void MyFunction();
```

Since I am not very good at programming yet, especially C++, I am kind of dependent on auto-complete, that are not appear for this. **Is there a way to activate this, since I really have no idea how to do it?**

Also; **Do I have to make an `DllImport` for every single dll I use, or  can I just enter a directory?**

Comment: You could always use this as a learning experience on how to interrogate API docs and code from those :P

Comment: Which IDE are you using ?

Comment: I'm working on Visual Studio 2012 if it's that what you mean.

Comment: And why are you trying to rewrite a wrapper by yourself ? EmguCV is already a .Net wrapper for OpenCV. I'm not sure you will have better performance by writing a wrapper by yourself.

Comment: Because I have never done it and want to learn it. And since it's just like three functions I thought it should be doable..

Comment: Even if, it is only three functions, they depend on classes that are also written in C++. But you're right, it is doable but it is probably not easy to do. About your original question, you should search for : `How to import a dll on Visual Studio 2012`. Your question is not directly related to OpenCV itself.